# JFreeChart & Image

Tags: jfreechart

Is it possible to cast an image/BufferedImage to JFreeChart?

Comment: You want to cast/convert an image to a chart? I don't understand how that might work

Comment: Do you want to make images/BufferedImages with Jfreechart?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Casting an image to JFree is not possbile. To create an image from JFreechart you can do the following:

```
BufferedImage objBufferedImage=objJFreechart.createBufferedImage(600,800);
ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(objBufferedImage, "png", bas);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

byte[] byteArray=bas.toByteArray();
```

This creates the byte[] .

Now you need to create the image from byte[]. The following does this.

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
File outputfile = new File("image.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```

The image gets created at the place where your project is created(local drive).

Comment: Another way to create image from JFreeChart is by using `ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(ouputstream,jfreechart,x,y)` function.

Comment: yannis hristofakis: that way, you don't have access to the BufferedImage. I needed this because the chart adds some padding which I couldn't get rid of by configuring the chart, so I had to crop the image - BufferedImage.getSubImage(...)

Answer (score 17):

JfreeChart takes data first and generate image using generic ChartUtilities class or any customized utility class.

```
ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(outputstream,getDataset(), width,height);
```

Maybe this can help you:[here](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/how-to-use-and-not-use-itext-and-jfreechart/)

Answer (score 4):

The `JFreeChart` object is for making images, it does not consume them and images cannot be converted into a JFreeChart object.
See: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html