# How to display Servlet generated image inot <IMG> html tag

Tags: jsp, servlets, jfreechart

I tried a lot but all in vain. I am not able to to display image from servlet into jsp.

I have developed a servlet which in turn calls another class that returns BufferedImage.

**In servlet I written**:

```
PngEncoder png =new PngEncoder(image,false,0,9);
    response.getOutputStream().write(png.pngEncode());
       response.getOutputStream().close();
```

**And in jsp I have written**:

```
IMG src="/WebApplication5/ChartServlet"
```

but when i run my web application nothing gets displayed.
When i directly browse by this url
http://localhost:8080/WebApplication5/ChartServlet
it showing :

> HTTP Status 500 - type Exception report message descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from
>        fulfilling this request. exception java.lang.NullPointerException note
>        The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>        available in the Sun Java System Application Server 9.1 logs. Sun Java
>       System Application Server 9.1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it tells you where to look - in the logs

Comment: Hey Bozho  thanks for your quick reply. I am using netbeen and not so much used to it. So please could you let me know where i can found the logs. i have gone through one log of netbeen View->ID log but didnt found any thing helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the png object is created OR not (if it is getting null). That could be the only reason why you should get a NullPointerException

Comment: Hi Ravi, i sorted out the HTTP Status 500 thanks for pointing towards that. Right now i checked whether the PNG object is getting created i    BufferedImage image = providerchart.createBufferedImage(480, 360, null);
           PngEncoder png = new PngEncoder(image, false, 0, 9);
            System.out.println(" image :-  "+png);

Comment: Hi Ravi, 
Thanks for your guiding me in  sorting  out the HTTP Status 500. I followed your instruction and I checked whether the PNG object is getting created 
   BufferedImage image = providerchart.createBufferedImage(480, 360, null);
   PngEncoder png = new PngEncoder(image, false, 0, 9);
   System.out.println(" image  :-  "+png);
 And in output I got this:- 
Image  :-  com.keypoint.PngEncoder@713caa
Means it’s not null. Still I am getting only blank page with no chart image.
Please guide me where i need to tweek.

Comment: Before writing the image to the outputstream, set the content type as response.setContentType("image/png");

Comment: response.setContentType("image/png");
commoditychart o_providerchart = new commoditychart();
JFreeChart providerchart= o_providerchart.produceAllCharts("1","2012-01-09","C:/Documents and Settings/irfanr/Desktop/WebApplication5/web/images/");
BufferedImage image = providerchart.createBufferedImage(480, 360, null);
PngEncoder png = new PngEncoder(image, false, 0, 9);
System.out.println(" image :-  "+png);
response.getOutputStream().write(png.pngEncode());  this is what i have written in servlet

Comment: providerchart= o_providerchart.produceAllCharts("1","2012-01-09","C:/Documents and Settings/irfanr/Desktop/WebApplication5/web/images/");
produceAllCharts:-
is the method of commoditychart class which produces charts and return to BufferedImage object. 
produceAllCharts parameters are (product id, date, path);
from these parameters i fetch data from database.
If i run only commoditychart class the chart get generated on the specified path.
But when i try to return the chart object that was genertaed in the commoditychart class to the servelt then its showing nothing in the browser.Thanks

Comment: Were you able to save the png image in the disk? Try to save that and see if it is getting saved.

Comment: I think you have to use PngEncoderB instead of PngEncoder. Have a look at this - http://catcode.com/pngencoder/. To convert BufferedImage, you have to use PngEncoderB.

Comment: If i write folowing lines in  produceAllCharts() method of commoditychart class.

File ifle2 = new File(imagepath + product_id + ".png");
imagepath:-  is the location to my image folder of my web application
product_id :- that i pass to rt now its value is 1.


ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(ifle2, chart, 650, 490, info);

commoditychart class contains main() method.
when i run this java file only the data gets fethced nicely and png image is created at the path given to it.

Comment: I think this is a simple solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272966/jfreechart-image

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravi for your time. I will try with your given urls. Thanks And warm regards

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravi. What i did, placed all the code of my class that was generating chart in the servlet and it worked like charm thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Great to see that finally you got a solution. I thought the code was in servlet.