# what is the equivalent class in itext7 for PdfGraphics2D class in itext5

Tags: itext7

I could not find any reference for PdfGraphics2D class in itext7. Please let me know how to migrate to latest itext7. We are using itext 2.1.5 currently doing a POC to migrate to itext7.

We are using itext to render graph in PDF document in our application. The PDF document itself generated using other library not using itext.

Comment: please give more information

Comment: `PdfGraphics2D` wasn't ported to iText 7. Although many people found that class useful, we focused on creating well-formed PDF's with iText 7. When using `PdfGraphics2D`, you lose all semantic information about the content, hence you can't create properly tagged PDF. Also: using `PdfGraphics2D` is a workaround, and the PDF syntax created when using `PdfGraphics2D` suffers from mismatches between Java syntax and PDF syntax. I don't think there are plans to port `PdfGraphics2D` to iText 7, but you are always welcome to do it yourself and contribute the code.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, can you please point me to a workaround/alternative for PdfGraphics2D. We use jFreeChart to draw the graph. The draw method requires 'void org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.draw(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D area, ChartRenderingInfo info) ' a Graphics Object

Comment: Joris provided a workaround.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm not really sure what tagging information I'd want to put on basic geometry like lines and filled squares anyway, but technically it would have been possible to use `RenderingHints` to pass through arbitrary tagging data via a `Graphics2D` anyway, it was more that `PDFGraphics2D` never implemented it for us. I don't really consider `PdfGraphics2D` to be a workaround, more a way to reuse code so that you don't have to write all your rendering logic twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a `JFreeChart` object to a `BufferedImage`.
See [JFreeChart & Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272966/jfreechart-image)

```
BufferedImage objBufferedImage=objJFreechart.createBufferedImage(600,800);
```

Once you have a BufferedImage, you can render it to PNG (again, see linked post), and tell iText to insert the PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use OrsonPDF to create the PDF from JFreeChart, then add that to your iText PDF document.  I wrote a blog post describing how to do this a while back:

https://jfree.github.io/orsonpdf/